# wxWidgets. Creating a new page within wxAuiNotebook on command

Tags: wxwidgets

How do I add a page to wxAUINoteBook? I wish to be able to click: File->New, and then have a new tab pop in. I understand how to do this using wxAuiMDIChildFrame within a parent frame but the child frame is a class on its own and a new page is not. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include "main.h"

MyFrame::MyFrame() 
    : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "AUItest", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(800, 450), wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
{
    wxMenuBar* menubar = new wxMenuBar;

    wxMenu* menufile = new wxMenu;

    menufile->Append(1001, "New");
    menufile->Append(1002, "Open");
    menufile->Append(1003, "Save");
    menufile->Append(1004, "Exit");

    menubar->Append(menufile, "File");

    SetMenuBar(menubar);

    wxAuiNotebook* notebook = new wxAuiNotebook(this, -1, wxPoint(-1, -1),
        wxSize(-1, -1), wxNB_TOP | wxAUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ACTIVE_TAB);
  
    wxPanel* panel1 = new wxPanel(notebook, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
    wxPanel* panel2 = new wxPanel(notebook, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);
    wxPanel* panel3 = new wxPanel(notebook, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize);

    notebook->AddPage(panel1, wxT("Sheet1"));
    notebook->AddPage(panel2, wxT("Sheet2"));
    notebook->AddPage(panel3, wxT("Sheet3"));

    Center();

}

MyFrame::~MyFrame()
{

}

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
EVT_MENU(1001, MyFrame::OnMenuNew)
EVT_MENU(1002, MyFrame::OnMenuOpen)
EVT_MENU(1003, MyFrame::OnMenuSave)
EVT_MENU(1004, MyFrame::OnMenuExit)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

void MyFrame::OnMenuNew(wxCommandEvent& event)
{

    //How do I add a page on command?

}

void MyFrame::OnMenuOpen(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
}

void MyFrame::OnMenuSave(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
}

void MyFrame::OnMenuExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close(true);
    event.Skip();
}
```

Thanks for the help,
I'm still learning.

Comment: there is no magic here. You just use the sane `notebook->AddPage()` call as in constructor. What seems to be the problem.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but didn't work. Am I missing something else?

Comment: define `doesn't work `. Doesn't compile? Crash? Doesnt add page? Please give the error if it errors out or post the backtrack if it asserts. Also - whats your platform and wx version.

Comment: identifier "notebook" is undefined. I'm using windows and wx3.1.5 not that it should matter.  How do I define "notebook"? Is it not already in the main frame?

Comment: you need to make it a class member. This is basic C++ issue. You need to learn basics first before going with `any` advanced library.

Comment: I already did in my header file.

Comment: There are no sizers...

Comment: @jake, and then you hide by Newington completely different object in constructor.